# Is it possible to implement one of two signatures in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

For example, let's say I want to accept an array of a specific type (say `User`) or an array *of arrays* of `Users` as a parameter.

In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
interface arrayTypeOne {...}
interface arrayTypeTwo {...}

export class MyClass {

    myMethod(args:MustBeOneOrTwo) {

    }
}
```

The flexibility is valuable to consumers of the API, so I don't think it's a good idea to break it into two methods. On the other hand, I'd really like to declare a type more specific than `all`.

Ideas?

Comment: What version of Typescript are you using?

Comment: the most recent one. (1.7.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More recent versions of Typescript have introduced the concept of *union types*, where you can specify that a parameter/variable is one of a list of types.

In your example, you would do:

```
interface arrayTypeOne {...}
interface arrayTypeTwo {...}

export class MyClass {

    myMethod(args: arrayTypeOne | arrayTypeTwo) {

    }
}
```

Comment: ooh -- didn't realize that had been added. Awesome. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @BryceJohnson Keep an eye on [What's new in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript) and the [Roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap) for other new features you may have missed.

Comment: Thanks for the links -- I definitely need to look through both and think about how they're relevant to me.